# Applying the Euclidean Algorithm by finding the greatest common divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find two integers $a,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ for which when applying the Euclidean algorithm for finding $\gcd(a,b)$, precisely 10 steps are required.

Comment: Work backwards. Take a typical Euclidean algorithm calculation, probably shorter than $10$ steps, and go upwards from the beginning.  Choosing quotients of $1$ will keep numbers from getting too big too quickly.

Comment: A lot of the tags are not relevant. I have removed abstract algebra, set theory, division algebra, and replaced it with elementary number theory

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Use two consecutive Fibonacci numbers. See how many steps it takes with $F_{n+1}$ and $F_n$ for some small values of $n$, and you’ll quickly see what’s going on. By the way, this will give the smallest possible example.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Apply the Euclidean Algorithm backwards, to increase the number of steps by 1 each time.

---

Another approach:

Find 2 numbers in which the Euclidean algorithm requires $> 10 $ steps. Truncate accordingly.